# IRepository with Inherited Classes

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

In keeping with the Repository pattern of data input, I've a question in regards to using inherited classes. For instance, suppose I would have the class...

```
class Employee

IEmployeeRepository
{
 Add(Employee employee);
}
```

This works fine, nothing wrong with it so far... but now let's say I continue on..

```
class Manager : Employee
```

Okay, now let's assume that I never need to enter a manager different than an Employee? What's the best approach here? Would a scenario such as ..

```
IEmployeeRepository
{
 Add<T>(T employee) where T : Employee
}
```

Be the best approach, or do I need to abstract a different repository for each type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are all employees, I would probably create an interface and constrain it to that.  For example:

```
IEmployeeRepository
{
 Add<T>(T employee) where T : IEmployee
}
```

Comment: I personally felt this was the best way to go, especially because I can set the return type to `T` and get it back for other methods in the Repository, if it is required. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something glaring at me.

Answer (score 0):

If things are being handled differently, then you should create another Repository for the new type.

If the two never have different logic (and they really shouldn't considering a Manager is still an Employee in your case), then you can re-use what you already have. You shouldn't even need to change the code (as long as Manager inherits from the Employee class):

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    Add(Employee employee);
}
```

Should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> let's assume that I never need to
>   enter a manager different than an
>   Employee

So you do not have an abstraction. You only have an `Employee` and you need a repository for that.

> do I need to abstract a different
>   repository for each type?

Yes if you have an abstraction of a few subclasses. The point is **you normally do not need a repository for abstract classes only for subclasses.**